# Using Coda 2's (or Coda, for that matter) Preview feature with CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, mamp, coda

I am using Coda 2 and MAMP Pro. Many sites I have built work great with the pair, and when it works, it works. By allowing me to specify a Site-Specific URL and then letting Coda know what that URL is, the preview feature works fantastic. Until I started using CakePHP...

The problem is that say I specify the URL "myawesomesite" and point it to my local site directory in MAMP Pro, and then run the servers. I can navigate to "http://myawesomesite:8888" and everything works great, even on sites using CakePHP. However, when I click "preview" in Coda, even after specifying the correct Local URL, Coda tries to append the file structure (as it should in most cases) to the URL. Meaning that I get a URL like this: "http://myawesomesite:8888/app/View/Passes/index.ctp"

Is there any way to override the normal URL formatting of Coda 2's preview function? Or any other solutions?

Answer (score 1):

I also use Coda 2 and CakePHP, and have the same issue. I've searched a lot and I'm 99.9% certain there's no way around it. Lots of people using web frameworks with Coda have the same problem, so it could be worth asking Coda for the feature - they're pretty responsive.

In terms of other solutions, I've started using Live Reload (http://livereload.com/). I work with two monitors, and have Coda in one screen, and Firefox open in the other. With Live Reload, whenever you save a file in Coda, Firefox will refresh and show your changes. No need to switch applications or press any keys, just code and glance over at your other window to see your changes. It's pretty awesome, but requires two monitors, or at least one big screen, to work really well.